# WPF page background loading...how to?

Tags: wpf, multithreading, user-interface, backgroundworker

I have a WPF Window with tab control. Every tabitem of tab control have a frame with PAGE as content...like this:

```
 <TabItem Name="Tab01">
   <Frame Name="Tab01Frame" />
 </TabItem>
```

```vb
 MyPage Tab01Page = New MyPage()
 Tab01Frame.Navigate(Tab01Page)
```

Now, I have this problem. Every page for tabitem is loading on window contructor and this cause a performance bottleneck for window. It takes some seconds to show.

Is there a way to load pages on background process?

Comment: How about not loading the pages until needed?

Comment: Yes, I tried this way and it seems ok...the only problem is that on first tabitem select there is a delay for page inizialitazion. Load the page on background is the best solution for me, if is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start, move the initialization code to the Loaded event (not in the constructor).  This will make the UI appear more responsive.  Also, use the Dispatcher object to background the task.

```
 private delegate void DelegateTypeYouDeclare();

 this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new DelegateTypeYouDeclare(MethodToCall), null);
```

Those are just first steps.  For a better example see the following MSDN article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx